# Selenium RC skips onclick() event after click on element

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I've got problem I can't deal with. I've tried to search answer in google, tried few things but it doesn't work any way.

Here is the problem:

I'm testing a log in page, where I type in login, password and click "login" button. Everything is OK, I'm logging to the page... But before log in (after click "login" button) there should appear a prompt with some info and "OK" button, the prompt is onclick() event of "login" button. I have no idea why the prompt doesn't show up, and I really need this prompt (I have similar problem with prompt "Do you want to save changes" which also doesn't appear - I assumed that selenium.click(..,..) and webelement.click() somehow bypass onclick() events. Do you have any idea what to do to have onclick() events working properly? I'm using IE (I have to) and selenium webdriver.

Ps.:if I do same actions "manually" the prompts do appear so I don't think that its a mistake in javascript.

Ps2.: Help me please I'm trying to fix it for a 5 h...:(

button code:

```
<input id="loginForm:loginCmdTest" type="submit" onclick="showAlertAndSubmitForm    ();clear_loginForm();" value="Login" name="loginForm:loginCmdTest">
```

java code:

```
selenium.type("id=loginForm:login", login);
selenium.type("id=loginForm:pass", pass);
selenium.click("id=loginForm:loginCmdTest");
```

Ps.3: ANYONE?? Any idea?

Comment: You need to post some code so that people can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain guess: You are using old, depreceated Selenium RC. What happens if you transfer it to webdriver approach?

Sample code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://your-test-site.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:login")).sendKeys("login");
driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:pass")).sendKeys("pass");
driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:loginCmdTest").click();
```

Comment: It... works :O
I've tried stuff like:
   selenium.type("id=loginForm:login", "log");
   selenium.type("id=loginForm:pass", "pas");
   
   driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:loginCmdTest")).click();
But it didnt work. I didn't knew that the way i set login and pass input have any meaning (importance?). Thanks man, now i will be using onlt the driver way of using webdriver (i found selenium. ... is easier [faster]). Thank you very much:D

Comment: happy to hear that my guess was right. Enjoy the webdriver ;)